# Use the call function of d3js on a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg

I am using react with d3js and I am trying to insert an axis on the svg element. The problem is that I don't know how to use the call function on react.

This is my render function:

```
render() {
  const cabra = this.props.cabra
  const width = this.props.size[0]
  const height = this.props.size[1]

  const tmpData = temperature.map((value,index) => {
    return {'indice':index,'value':value}
  })

  const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                   .rangeRound([0, width]);
  xScale.domain(d3.extent(tmpData, function(d) { return d.indice; }));

  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                   .rangeRound([height,0]);
  yScale.domain(d3.extent(tmpData, function(d) { return d.value; }));

  const sparkLine = d3.line()
    .x( d => xScale(d.indice) )
    .y( d => yScale(d.value) )

 const sparkLinePaths =
   <path
     d={sparkLine(tmpData)}
     className='line'
     style={{fill:'none',strokeWidth:2, stroke: "red"}}
   />

   const yAxis = axisLeft()
   .scale(yScale)

return <svg width={width} height={height}>
  <g>        
    {sparkLinePaths}
  </g>
</svg>
}
```

I tried modifying the return so that it would return the axis:

```
 return <svg width={width} height={height}>
      <g>       
        {yAxis} 
        {sparkLinePaths}
      </g>
    </svg>
```

But it didn't work. Can anyone give me a help?

Thanks in advance,
Israel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before anything else: your `yAxis` constant is just the *axis generator*, it doesn't draw any axis.

Most of D3 examples use the following approach to draw the axis: first, they define the axis generator (here I'm using `axisBottom`)...

```
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);
```

... and then the `call` the axis on a group selection:

```
selection.call(axis);
```

However, you don't need to use `call`. You can simply create a variable that already combines the axis generator with the group element the axis will be drawn on.

According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_call),

```
selection.call(foo);
```

is almost the same of:

```
foo(selection);
```

I said *almost* because...

> The only difference is that selection.call always returns the selection and not the return value of the called function.

Therefore, you don't need to use `call`. Just do:

```
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)(groupSelection);
```

Or, in your case:

```
const yAxis = axisLeft().scale(yScale)(groupSelection);
```

Where `groupSelection` is, of course, the selection with the `<g>` element that will contain the axis.

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var scale = d3.scaleLinear().range([10, 290]);
var g = svg.append("g");
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)(g);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Gerardo for your answer, the point is that I have no reference to the G element since I am using react. I just throw the JSFX elements inside the G element, but I don't know how to reference it from the functions.